# how much rows handsontable can load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

```
Exception in queued task: Error: Security brake: Too much TRs. Please define height for your table, which will enforce scrollbars.
at WalkontableTable._doDraw (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:12859:15)
at WalkontableTable.draw (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:12760:10)
at Walkontable.draw (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:10435:16)
at Handsontable.TableView.render (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:2781:11)
at Object.selection.selection.refreshBorders (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:646:21)
at render (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:1398:17)
at $.fn.handsontable (client/libs/handsontable-0.10.5/jquery.handsontable.full.js?37b46fd989b9a974c3501865b51effd7adec37e4:2382:35)
```

i got this error at client browser console when i load more than 1500 rows in handsontable-10.0.5, currently i used data binding to load these amount of rows

is there any way to load more than 1500 rows in handsontable ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested a jsFiddle with 100,000 rows in handsontable, which works great.

You need to be very careful when displaying a large number of rows, because the browser will most likely run very slow.

I suggest taking the error message advice, and define height for your table, which will enforce scrollbars.

This way handsontable will only render the visible part of the table, and not the full number of rows.

Comment: there is no problem in my local system & loading from localhost but it shows error when i load it from my amazon instance